# AWS KeyConditionExpression dynamodb query

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb

I'm trying to use the query expression an getting

**ATTEMPT EDIT - 1 PASS**
An error occurred (ValidationException) when calling the Query operation: Invalid KeyConditionExpression: Syntax error; token: "{", near: "{""

This query looks like

```
aws dynamodb query --table-name name-of-table --key-condition-expression 'id=:91'
```

I've tried '"id"="91"', ':id=":91"', etc.

id is the partition key so this is also the required attribute needed.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this

```
aws dynamodb query --table-name name-of-table --key-condition-expression 'id = :idval' --expression-attribute-values '{":idval":{"S":"91"}}'
```

You have to use value substitution on attributes. You can optionally use attribute name substitution.

Note i've assume your id attribute is of type String. Change it to "N" if its a number.

Comment: My query is complicated and this did help.  I updated the question with the Exception I now receive.

Comment: May I suggest you roll back the changes to your question, as this answer now makes no sense. If you post this as a new question I will answer it.